# spring boot JPA returns null object when it finds a null attribute eg date is null

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, angular7

I wanted to load an object from the database that contains more
attributes, one of which is null (e.g : date), using spring boot JPA
that returns a null object because it found the date is null despite 
the object exists in the database. Please who can who can tell me how I solve this problem

```
@Entity @IdClass(Exemple.class) @Table(name= "table") public class
Exemple implements Serializable{

@Id @Column(columnDefinition = "id_activite") private Integer idActivite;

//the Problem is here

@Column(columnDefinition = "date_debut_prevue") @Nullale private Calendar dateDebutPrevue;

//Other attribute and Id

@Id ...

// Getters && setters

}

//Query Repository

@Query("SELECT ar FROM table ar where ar.idActivity = ?1  ") 
List<Activitie> findAllPositionByIdActivitie(Integer idActivitie);
```

Comment: no that cannot be the cause

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a native query and not a JPQL query.

The query must use the Entity name in the FROM clause not the table name.

```
@Query("SELECT ar FROM Exemple ar where ar.idActivity = ?1  ") 
List<Activitie> findAllPositionByIdActivitie(Integer idActivitie);
```